Trouble importing csv containing email address for automation script
Attempting to automate an email being sent overnight using email addresses in a csv. Script cannot call the addresses - "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address." The csv contains two addresses with the header: EmailAddresses
First.Lastname@Domain.com;
First.Lastname@Domain.com;
Below is the script
$date = get-date -Format dd-MM-yyyy--hh-mm-SS
$Transcript = "$($PSScriptRoot)\Transcript\Transcript-$($date).txt"
Start-Transcript $Transcript
#Checking Path to address csv file
$checkCSVPath = Test-Path -Path "%FilePath%\Addresses.csv"
If(!($checkCSVPath))
    {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "Path failed"
    Exit
    }
    else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Path found"
    }
#Checking smtp port
$checkPort = test-netconnection '%SMTPAddress%' -port %%
If (!($checkPort) -or ($checkPort.TcpTestSucceeded -eq $false)) {
    Write-Host -foregroundcolor red "Port failed"
}
Else {
    Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "Port test complete"
}
#Checking path the email template
$checkPath = Test-path -path "%FilePath%\Template\Email.htm"
    if(!($checkPath))
    {
        Write-Host -foregroundcolor red "Path failed"
        Exit
    }
    else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "Path Found!"
        }
            $Addresses = Import-Csv -path "%FilePath%\Addresses.csv" -header "EmailAddress"
            $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage  
            $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient "%SMTPAddress%"
            $msg.From = "%FromAddress"
            $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
            #$msg.To.Add($Mailto)
            $msg.BCC.Add("$($Addresses)")
            $msg.Subject = "%Subject%"
            $MailBody =   Get-Content -path "%FilePath%\Template\Email.htm"
            $msg.Body = $MailBody
            # send the email
            $smtp.Send($msg)   
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "Email Sent"       
Stop-Transcript


This is the output error:
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."
At %FilePath%\Email.ps1:37 char:33


            $msg.BCC.Add("$($Addresses)")



                            ~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException




Your script is barely readable as displaying as a block. Furthemore, what is the question ?

issue is that the email addresses are not being pulled from the csv error generated it - "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

Please [edit] the question and add the header and 2-3 lines of the .csv file as text.

Added to the original question - EmailAddresses First.Lastname@Domain.com; First.Lastname@Domain.com;

Import-Csv will output one object per row, each with properties corresponding to the column(s) in the CSV file.
To add the EmailAddress property value of each as recipients on the message, loop over $Addresses and assign the values individually, like this:
$Addresses |ForEach-Object {
  $msg.BCC.Add($_.EmailAddress)
}

